# Batch file name similar to windows keyword

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Is there any way that , I can create a batch file with a name similar to that of windows key word.

Example :-

If a I had created a batch file with name XYZ.bat and add its location  in the environment variables path , then when ever I type XYZ in the cmd , the XYZ.bat file would be invoked.

I want to do the same but with windows keyword , like wmic or xcopy

Is there any way to spoof the windows keyword using a bat file

Comment: Yes you can; may I ask why you want to?

Comment: I want to create a batch file with name wmic. Whenever I type wmic in cmd , I want the batch file to be invoked.

Comment: But why?  What do you want the batch file to do?  I ask because such a request sounds rather nefarious..

Comment: I just want to  echo something like check. Just wanted to see, how one can change the windows keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Type `doskey /?` for how to do this. Where filenames are the same the order is  com, exe, then bat (type `set pathext`.

```
doskey mymacro=c:\someprogram.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

***Note - Spoofing a command is ripe for abuse. Please use the following responsibly***

As bgalea says, you can use doskey to define a macro.

For example, create the following batch script and put it somewhere that is included in your PATH:

**echo.bat**

```
@echo My echo: %*
```

Then use DOSKEY to define a macro for echo:

```
doskey echo=echo.bat $*
```

Now, when you attempt to ECHO text from the command line, it will run echo.bat instead:

```
C:\test>echo Hello world!
My echo: Hello world!
```

However, DOSKEY macros do not work within batch scripts. If you want your replacement script to run within another script, then you will have to use `call echo`. That would be necessary anyway, since a batch script will not return to the caller unless CALL is used.

**test.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Hello world!
call echo Goodbye!
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
C:\test>test
Hello world!
My echo: Goodbye!
```

Also note that DOSKEY macros do not work within FOR IN() clauses. In such cases you would need to use `call echo`

```
C:\test>for /f "delims=" %A in ('echo Hello world!') do @echo %A
Hello world!

C:\test>for /f "delims=" %A in ('call echo Hello world!') do @echo %A
My echo: Hello world!
```

Neither do DOSKEY macros work on the right side of a pipe. Again, CALL would need to be used. *(This example is a bit odd, but it gets the point across)*

```
C:\test>echo anything | echo Hello world!
Hello world!

C:\test>echo anything | call echo Hello world!
My echo: Hello world!
```

However, DOSKEY macros *do* work on the left side of a pipe:

```
C:\test>echo Hello world! | findstr "^"
My echo: Hello world!
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering the question. But using doskey spoofs the keyword in only current cmd instance . When I open new cmd , the change isn't reflected.

Comment: You typically set a autoexec macro loading your doskey macros. Edit `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and add `AutoRun` as a string. And see `/MACROFILE=filename` Specifies a file of macros to install.